Problema al implementar el juego Wordle en JavaScript: validación y comparación de palabras
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto para implementar el juego Wordle en JavaScript y me he encontrado con algunos problemas. En el juego, el usuario debe adivinar una palabra de 5 letras, y el sistema debe validar la palabra ingresada y proporcionar feedback sobre las letras que están en la posición correcta, incorrecta o no están en la palabra.
He escrito el siguiente código básico para validar la entrada del usuario y comparar las letras, pero no estoy seguro de si esta es la mejor manera de hacerlo:


const palabraSecreta = "CANDE";
const intento = "CANTO";

function validarIntento(intento, palabraSecreta) {
    let resultado = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < intento.length; i++) {
        if (intento[i] === palabraSecreta[i]) {
            resultado += "✔️"; // Letra correcta en la posición correcta
        } else if (palabraSecreta.includes(intento[i])) {
            resultado += ""; // Letra correcta en la posición incorrecta
        } else {
            resultado += "❌"; // Letra incorrecta
        }
    }

    return resultado;
}

console.log(validarIntento(intento, palabraSecreta)); // Salida esperada: "✔️✔️❌❌"



Mis preguntas son:

¿Hay una forma más eficiente o elegante de comparar las letras de las dos palabras y proporcionar el feedback correcto?
¿Cómo puedo manejar mejor la validación de entradas incorrectas (por ejemplo, palabras que no tienen exactamente 5 letras o contienen caracteres no válidos)?
¿Cómo puedo mejorar la estructura y la eficiencia del código para que sea más fácil de mantener y ampliar en el futuro?

Cualquier consejo o sugerencia sería muy apreciado. ¡Gracias de antemano por su ayuda!

Aveces buscar que el código sea más eficiente te lleva a situaciones donde el código no es tan legible.

Redacta tu pregunta de tal manera a centrarse en un solo problema. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.



const palabraSecreta = "CANDE";
const intento = "CANTO";

function validarIntento( intento, palabraSecreta ) {

    let resultado = [intento.length];
    let resto = "";

    for( let i = 0; i < intento.length; i++ ) {
        if( intento[ i ] === palabraSecreta[ i ] ) {
            resultado[ i ] = "✔️"; // Letra correcta en la posición correcta
            resto += "#";
        } 
        else {
            resto += palabraSecreta[ i ];
            resultado[ i ] = "#";
        }
    }


    for( let i = 0; i < intento.length; i++ ) {
        if( resto[ i ] !== "#" ) {
            if( resto.includes( intento[ i ] )) {
                resultado[ i ] = ""; // Letra correcta en la posición incorrecta
                resto = resto.replace( intento[ i ], "#" );
            } 
            else {
                resultado[ i ] = "❌"; // Letra incorrecta
            }
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}

console.log( validarIntento( "zrrrr", "radio"  ));
console.log( validarIntento( "radio", "rdaio" ));
console.log( validarIntento( "menea", "pelma" ));
console.log( validarIntento( intento, palabraSecreta )); // Salida esperada: "✔️✔️❌❌"



Como podés apreciar, le realicé unas pequeñas modificaciones a tu código, ya que tenía un pequeño desliz, si por ejemplo, la palabra a encontrar era "santo" y se ingresa como intento "nnnnn", te devolvía "✔️",  lo cual no es correcto.
El funcionamiento es bastante sencillo, hago una primer recorrida, solo para verificar las letras que están bien ubicadas, si lo está, agrego a resultado que es un array, el valor correspóndiente, y a resto el "#", que me va a servir para identificar que posiciones del array debo verificar en la siguiente recorrida (como seguramente dedujiste, en resto quedan las letras que no estaban bien ubicadas o eran erróneas y los "#", para luego verificar si una letra está contenida o no).
Si la letra no está bien ubicada, a resto le agrego la letra que debe estar, y a resultado el "#" (solo para control).
En el segundo for, primero verifico que la letra de resto sobre la que estoy iterando no sea "#" (si lo es no hago nada), y ejecuto el resto de tu código, al que solo le agregue una linea, que reemplaza por "#" la letra encontrada, para que no se valide otra vez.
Ahora, este código devuelve un array, no se si te sirve así o lo convertis a string*.
PD: la salida esperada para "cande", "canto" es "✔️✔️✔️❌❌".
PD2: sería conveniente pasar todo a minúsculas, para evitar errores.

La salida esperada de CANTO es ✔️✔️✔️❌❌ y no ✔️✔️❌❌ como señala el comentario de tu código
Tu dices:
¿Hay una forma más eficiente o elegante de comparar las letras de las dos palabras y proporcionar el feedback correcto?
Muchas veces (la mayoría diría yo), la elegancia y la eficiencia son contrarios. Mientras más elegante el código puede ser menos eficiente y viceversa. No es una regla, pero pasa.
Está bien preocuparse por la eficiencia, no obstante, para recorrer una sola palabra de unas cuantas letras, no tiene mucho sentido
Por ejemplo, te he puesto un código abajo al final de esta respuesta, aquel código quedo de esa manera al agregar extensibilidad y validaciones que tu señalabas, antes de eso era simplemente:


function validarIntento(intento, palabra) {
  let exactas = Array.from(palabra).map((a, i) => intento[i] === a ? "✔️" : a);
  return Array.from(intento).map((a, i) => {
    if ("✔️" === exactas[i]) return exactas[i];
    return exactas.includes(a) ? "" : "❌";
  }).join("");
}

console.log(validarIntento("CANTO","CANDE"))
console.log(validarIntento("NNNNN","CANTO"))



Pero este código no valida y no sirve para nada más que mostrar en consola. Mientras vas agregando funcionalidades, inevitablemente queda un código algo más desordenado.
¿Cómo puedo mejorar la estructura y la eficiencia del código para que sea más fácil de mantener y ampliar en el futuro?
Es un código de 10 líneas no da para preocuparse mucho por eso. En el futuro lo cambias y ya.
Pero para responderte, te diria que faltan al menos 2 cosas:

Devolver la letra y un estado, porque, así como lo tienes te sirve solo para imprimir en consola.  Cuando lo quieras integrar a una interfaz gráfica seguro vas a tener que realzar cambios
Mantener el número de intentos, que es parte del juego




class Worlde {
    static Status = {
        EXACT: "✔️",
        ALMOST: "",
        NONE: "❌"
    }

    #word;
    #arrayWord;
    constructor(word) {
        this.#word = word.toUpperCase()
        this.#arrayWord = Array.from(this.#word);
        this.intentos = 0;
    }

    validate(intento) {
        intento = intento.toUpperCase();

        //Validación para que solo acepte letras
        if (!/^[A-Z]*$/g.test(intento)) throw new Error("Hay caracteres no validos")

        //Esto no es realmente necesario, pero ya que buscabas algo de eficiencia
        //esto ahorra una iteración cuando la palabra es exacta
        if (intento === this.#word) return this.#generateResult(this.#arrayWord.map(a=>({ letra: a, status: Worlde.Status.EXACT }), true));

        let exactas = this.#arrayWord.map((a, i) => intento[i] === a ? { letra: a, status: Worlde.Status.EXACT } : a);
        let partialResult = Array.from(intento).map((a, i) => {
            if (Worlde.Status.EXACT === exactas[i].status) return exactas[i];
            return { letra: a, status: exactas.includes(a) ? Worlde.Status.ALMOST : Worlde.Status.NONE };
        });

        return this.#generateResult(partialResult);
    }


    #generateResult(result, victory=false){
        const intentos = ++this.intentos;
        return {
            result,
            victory,
            intentos,
            printConsole() {
                console.log(this.result.map(a => a.status).join(""));
            }
        }
    }
}


const worle =  new Worlde("CANDE");
const result = worle.validate("CANto")
console.log(result);
result.printConsole();

worle.validate("denca").printConsole();
worle.validate("nnnnn").printConsole();
worle.validate("cacad").printConsole();




let result ..., si no será el resultado final sino uno parcial, ¿porqué mejor no crear una variable con un nombre apropiado, como partialResult o algo similar?, de esa forma el código es un poco más legible y se entiende a primera vista lo que ocurre. Piensa que la asignación que haces sobre result incluye elementos de la asignación incial de la misma variable, lo cual, cuando se trata de código extenso, como en este caso, hace que se pierda un poco la legibilidad. Ahora, es mi humilde opinión, no hay nada de incorrecto en hacerlo como lo haces. Saludos

@MauricioContreras Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de revisar el código. Creo que tienes toda la razón
